# Css property to scale body accordingly to screen as if it were an image

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I work for a publicity agency, where my boss designs mockups in Photoshop (based on his 1920x1080 screen), and where the website final layout must look 90% like his, very close. We don't use Bootstrap (or any css framework) as he defines margins and columns himself, so Bootstrap gets more in the way than helping.

We use a mockup image for 16:9 aspect ratio, that can be opened in the browser and fits perfectly if you're viewing it on any 16:9 monitor. When we move on to actually creating the html / css page, we're unable to achieve that effect, and rely on many media queries to 'fix' each bigger or lower resolution than the one it was designed in.

Is there a way to make an element - or the whole body, to simply scale from the original design, so that we don't need to do any media queries between screens that share the same aspect ratio?

This way, we would only have three media queries: One for 16:9, one for 9:16 and one for 16:10.

Additional Info: I'm looking for something that does similar to the transform: scale property, but that one in particular doesn't work here (using it causes problems with buttons becoming unclickable in some browsers).

Answer (score 3):

....Technically, yes, but in reality, it's a lot of work, and won't really save you any time. Your best bet is to go back and start using Bootstrap. At least, using the `col`s and `row`s of Bootstrap Bootstrap is a *fantastic* tool for building responsive websites, for people who aren't comfortable building responsive websites on their own.

I... have a lot of things to say.

First of all,

1. If you're working on building websites, you really, *really* should have two monitors attached to your computer. Personally, I prefer having one small (1280x800) and one large (1920x1080) screen, because it makes me more aware and comfortable with responsive design. But that's my personal preference, and many people prefer two large monitors. At the very least, you should also have a 1080p screen, so you can work directly on it.
2. To answer your question directly, this strategy is *not* going to work for tablets and phones, because the aspect ratio on desktop computers is "landscape", but in mobile devices the aspect ratio is "portrait". If you've ever tried to view a 1920x1080 image in mobile, you'll immediately see why this a problem.

HOWEVER. If you're looking for a way to scale the entire website based upon the body, ...the approach that comes to mind first, REM, is quite popular, and I assume you've already tried it, but... I'll clarify, just in case.

You can define ***everything*** using percent, EM or REM (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `p`, `borders`, `padding`, `margin`, `height`, `fontsize`, `box-shadow` etc... Everything. The phrase `px` should not appear in your stylesheet.) , and then scale the website with a simple series of media queries like this:

```
@media( min-width:1200px){
    html,body{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
@media( min-width:1400px){
    html,body{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
@media( min-width:1600px){
    html,body{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
@media( min-width:1800px){
    html,body{
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}
```

Which will cause the entire website to scale. Obviously, if you're working with a theme or framework(Like Bootstrap), you'll need to modify that framework to use REM too.

#3.The last thing that I have to say is that most websites DON'T look exactly the same on 720p screens vs 1080p screens. For example, take StackOverflow itself. This is what the current page we're looking at looks like:

```
div#left-sidebar {
    width: 164px;
}

#sidebar {/*Right sidebar*/
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}

div#mainbar {/*Center section*/
    width: calc(100% - 300px - 24px);    
}

#content {/*And this wrapper around it all*/
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: calc(100% - 164px);/*left sidebar*/
}
```

If you look at it, the entire website is more or less `max-width:1480px`. If it gets smaller than that, the sidebars stay the same size, but the middle section has `width:100%` and shrinks to fit the screen.

At around 1000px, StackOverflow gives up and hides the right sidebar, because there's not enough space, but it STILL doesn't change the size of any fonts or icons, *ever*. (On *any* screen size, from 1920px all the way down to tablet.)

A good designer should keep this kind of "responsive design" in mind, and give his programmers a design that can shrink cleanly, in this way.

Comment: Once you get to complex designs, with lots of absolute elements, Bootstrap gets more in the  way than it helps. I am able to to make the website responsive after some sets of media queries with no trouble, but at least for the same aspect ratios, I wanted to be able to write so I don't need media queries there, only when we change to landscape (tablet/mobile).

Comment: Also, I am looking for something exactly like the 'transform' function, but without its flaws (it has a lot, including elements not being clicable at the same place the transform takes the buttons to)

Comment: @RafaelOliveira As far as I'm aware, there is no magic solution like that. There's another strategy I've seen people use with SASS/SCSS, though. Do you use SASS? If so, I can go into more detail.

Comment: @RafaelOliveira `Once you get to complex designs, with lots of absolute elements, Bootstrap gets more in the way than it helps.` I agree that Bootstrap has some strong opinions about things, but I've found overriding Bootstrap classes with the values I want to be very effective... Could you share with us an example of a design where you found Bootstrap to be useless, so we're on the same page?

Comment: @Elizer yes we do use SASS, for most projects. As for Bootstrap, it is possible to override its classes, but when I tried it for a fresh project, I found myself doing more overriding than actually using its column breakpoints, which are easy to implement. It also doesn't give me this ability I'm looking for, between resolutions that share the same aspect ratio. Specially because I own a small monitor (and the pandemic isn't allowing me to get a new one): although it looks perfect on my screen, the layout breaks on his, even with Bootstrap. The layouts have lots of custom margins, padding, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You’re looking for `vw` css unit. (Not sure if you need `vh` as well).

Checkout this website for an intuitive understanding of how those units work: https://sparanoid.com

`vw` unit is relative to viewport width. So if you code everything in `vw`. your website will behave like an image, just what you ask for.

Comment: I'm not asking for workflow advice or opinion, my question is very clear: I'm asking if there's something I can wrap and resize a container element without changing its appearance / aspect ratio. Your answer doesn't work like I asked, not even close, and questioning my boss is not an option, neither for me not for your answer, which went off topic.

Comment: Furthermore, what's wrong with Photoshop? He isn't designing basic app ui/ux like Instagram for instance, he's designing fully-artistic pages for business, with advanced concepts. He needs lots of graphic resources, which software like Adobe XD, for instance, could never provide.

Comment: @rafael I apologize for my prejudice. I’m in no position to comment on anything without fully understand the context.